# Graphs not correct after disk space issue during the test

Tags: jmeter

I ran a test for 48hrs from command line. Graphs are generated after the test finished and it is observed that graphs are being displayed only for 9.5hrs.  During the test disk was full at 2 time periods and I do not know the exact clock/relative time when it was full. I cleared the space on the disk when I noticed it.  What could be the issue?  If the graphs are generated incorrectly due to lack of disk space, then is there way to get the graphs for the remaining 38.5hrs?
Thanks.

Comment: Any feedback on answer, if ok you should accept it and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran out of disk space then unfortunately you :

- lost results
- potentially broke the test as it can impact performances

You will have to ensure you have enough disk space.

Regarding graphs generations with jmeter-plugins ensure you have enough memory for the jvm (-Xmx property)

Comment: The command I am using on the jmeter box to start the test is:
`../bin/jmeter -n -t ../scripts/$testScriptFile -l ../results/"$datestamp"_$testName/results-gr.csv  -JTEST_RESULTS_FILE=../results/"$datestamp"_$testName/results-gr.csv -JforcePerfmonFile=true -JtestName="$datestamp"_$testName -r`
And heap setting on remote hosts is:
`-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m`

Comment: heap settings seems ok.